# Composite Primary Key JPA representation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having a tough time mapping composite primary keys joins in hibernate. Here is a simplified picture of my schema. Please note, that I cannot change the schema.

[Simplified Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3hpS.png)

Here is how the classes are coded.

Tree class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
public class Tree implements Serializable {
   @EmbeddedId
   protected TreePK treePK;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tree")
  private Activity activity;
}
```

Tree PK Class

```
@Embeddable
public class TreePK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    //this is a foreign key from the volume table
    @Column(name = "volume_id")
    private Integer volumeId;
}
```

Volume class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "volume")
public class Volume implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private Integer id;
}
```

Activity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class Activity implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @JoinColumn(name = "tree_id", referencedColumnName = "id")    
   @OneToOne
   private Tree tree;
}
```

For Activity class:
Tree has a composite primary key. Activity has a foreign key on "one" of the columns (id) in Tree's composite primary key. 
The following line in Activity class

`@JoinColumn(name = "tree_id", referencedColumnName = "id")`

throws an exception

*referencedColumnNames(id) of com.corp.Activity.tree referencing com.corp.Tree not mapped to a single property*

How do I build such a relation in Hibernate? I have to map to a single property (id) although the primary key is composite.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that this approach is consistent? If your primary key is composite — then how can anything reference SINGLE entity by only one column of composite id? If in reality this is possible — then this single column is REAl primary key and you can use it as such in hibernate,

Answer (score 0):

Neither Eclipselink nor Hibernate can do this. Many years ago OpenJPA was the only JPA implementaion which could do this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try using OpenJPA as the provider instead of Hibernate.

Comment: @b0ri pleasy, try and if it will work — let me know.